# Use request module to retrieve JSON and return value

Tags: json, node.js, request

I use this [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module to make HTTP request in Nodejs

Sample code:

```
module.exports.getToken = function(){
    var token ;

    request(validLoginRequest, function(err,resp,body){
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
        console.log("from request(): token=" + json.accesstoken);
        token = json.accesstoken;
    });

    console.log("getToken() returns:" + token);
    return token;
}
```

But the `token` is always `undefined`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You've fallen into the classic node asynch trap. The code in the top level function of your module will return before the callback in the inner request function happens. token is not yet defined when you return it.

The simplest solution would be to pass a callback down from the outer function and call it from the callback returned to the request function. If that's not satisfying you could use the $q library to return a promise or find a module that will do synchronous http calls.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrote your code as per @Robert Moskal's response.

```
module.exports.getToken = function(callback){

    request(validLoginRequest, function(err,resp,body){
        var token ;
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
        console.log("from request(): token=" + json.accesstoken);
        token = json.accesstoken;

        console.log("getToken() returns:" + token);
        callback(token);
    });
}
```

Comment: But I want to return **token** as a variable. Using your code I have to define the callback function, what if I only want to pass the token to another variable ?

In other language (.NET) for example, we can simply do  
  
    `string getToken() {
        string token = "";
        ... //do something to get the token
        return token;
    }`  

  
Is there such way in Nodejs ?

I also want to store the token as class property named **`loginToken`** in a file named `tokenbuilder.js` so that later I can use : `tokenbuilder.loginToken` . How do I do it ?